Part bound and part living thing
They put a crooked barb upon my head,
In honor of my name.
At my right hand is a high place
To hold the one who came.
And at my left a hearty meal
Prepared for those I’ve led.
Below my feet a tumultuous cry
Sounds across the ocean bed.
As for me, I wear a ring
For I am part bound
And part living thing.
Who or what am I? (7 4)

A classic riddle, but reimagined. Didn't see it on PSE so I don't think it's a duplicate.

This riddle indirectly suggests a

 compass rose - a diagram used to display the directions: north, east, south, and west

They put a crooked barb upon my head, In honor of my name.

 north at the top, which is a crooked anagram of thorn, a barb

At my right hand is a high place, To hold the one who came.

 east at the right, which holds seat, a special chair of one in eminence, the status represented by it

And at my left a hearty meal, prepared for those I’ve led.

 west at the left, which is a prepared anagram of stew, the meal

Below my feet a tumultuous cry sounds across the ocean bed.

 south at your feet, tumultuously anagrammed is shout the cry

As for me, I wear a ring

 The contemporary compass rose appears as two rings, one smaller and set inside the other. The outside ring denotes true cardinal directions while the smaller inside ring denotes magnetic cardinal directions.


For I am part bound, and part living thing.

 Compass meaning an enclosing limit, and a rose the living flower.

